# Докер контейнер работает на ПК но не работает на сервере

Tags: c#, .net, telegram-bot, docker

В контейнере лежит телеграмм бот. На компе работает а вот на сервере нет. Просто закрывается.
В статусе контейнера пишет `Exited (0) 22 seconds ago`
`docker ps` ничего не показывает. 
Выполнение программы доходит то

```
async Task HandleUpdateAsync(ITelegramBotClient botClient, Update update, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Из примера
https://telegrambots.github.io/book/1/example-bot.html

```
using Telegram.Bot;
using Telegram.Bot.Exceptions;
using Telegram.Bot.Extensions.Polling;
using Telegram.Bot.Types;
using Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums;

var botClient = new TelegramBotClient("{YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE}");

using var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

// StartReceiving does not block the caller thread. Receiving is done on the ThreadPool.
var receiverOptions = new ReceiverOptions
{
    AllowedUpdates = { } // receive all update types
};
botClient.StartReceiving(
    HandleUpdateAsync,
    HandleErrorAsync,
    receiverOptions,
    cancellationToken: cts.Token);

var me = await botClient.GetMeAsync();

Console.WriteLine($"Start listening for @{me.Username}");
Console.ReadLine();

// Send cancellation request to stop bot
cts.Cancel();

async Task HandleUpdateAsync(ITelegramBotClient botClient, Update update, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Only process Message updates: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message
    if (update.Type != UpdateType.Message)
        return;
    // Only process text messages
    if (update.Message!.Type != MessageType.Text)
        return;

    var chatId = update.Message.Chat.Id;
    var messageText = update.Message.Text;

    Console.WriteLine($"Received a '{messageText}' message in chat {chatId}.");

    // Echo received message text
    Message sentMessage = await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(
        chatId: chatId,
        text: "You said:\n" + messageText,
        cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
}

Task HandleErrorAsync(ITelegramBotClient botClient, Exception exception, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var ErrorMessage = exception switch
    {
        ApiRequestException apiRequestException
            => $"Telegram API Error:\n[{apiRequestException.ErrorCode}]\n{apiRequestException.Message}",
        _ => exception.ToString()
    };

    Console.WriteLine(ErrorMessage);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

У меня там сразу идет Console.WriteLine и его уже не выводит. У меня висят сообщения  в боте так что сразу после запуска он должен их получить и ответить но этого не происходит. Хотя на ПК в контейнере все хорошо работает.
С чем может быть это связано?

Comment: а логи остановленного контейнера проверяли?

Comment: Я пишу docker logs [OPTIONS] CONTAINER команду и там ничего, собственно просто вывод того что у меня пишет в коносли. Причем я уже проверил код только из примера и все равно не работает. В боте моего кода нет, только тот что в документации

Comment: Добавил код из документации в пост на случай если ссылка в будущем сломается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По всей видимости `Console.ReadLine()` не ставит код на паузу в докере.

Создайте ожидалку вместо `Console.ReadLine()`, например.

```cs
var waiter = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
waiter.Wait();
Console.WriteLine("Stopping bot");
```

Добавьте метод

```
private void Stop()
{
    waiter.Set();
}
```

И в методе `HandleUpdateAsync` напишите например при получении команды `/stop` от себя, то есть не позволяйте бота остановить любому пользователю, а только себе.

```cs
if (/*получена команда /stop от админа бота*/)
    Stop();
```

Comment: Большое спасибо.